Is the following sequence bounded?
I want to prove the complexity of an algorithm I designed. To do this I need the following to be true:
Let $f(n)$ be a function in both $\Omega(n^{-5/2})$ and $\mathcal{O}(n^{-3/2})$ and let $\alpha$ be a constant $\alpha \approx 2.956$. The following series needs to be bounded:
$\begin{align*}
   \beta_1&=1\\
   \beta_i &= 1+\beta_{i-1}\frac{f(i-1)}{f(i)\alpha}
\end{align*}$
Does anyone know a way to prove that this is true?

I don't think it always does. If you take $f(n)=n^{-5/2}+\frac12 \sin(n) n^{-5/2}$ for  example. Then $(\beta_i)$ will not converge.  But for this $f$ the sequence $(\beta_i$) is still bounded.

Answer : the sequence $\beta_i$ is not necessarily bounded.
Consider $f(n) > 0$ for all $n$. Clearly, $\beta_i \ge 0$ for all $i$. In fact, for all $i$,
$$\beta_{i+1} \ge \mathrm{max}\left\{ 1, \dfrac{\beta_i f(i)}{f(i+1) \alpha} \right\} \ge \dfrac{ f(i)}{f(i+1) \alpha}.$$
Consider $f(n) = n^{-3/2}$ if $n$ is odd and $f(n) = n^{-5/2}$ when $n$ is even. Then for every odd $i$, we have
$$\beta_{i+1} \ge  \dfrac{ i^{-3/2}}{(i+1)^{-5/2} \alpha}  =  \dfrac{ (i+1)^{5/2}}{i^{3/2} \alpha} \ge \dfrac{i}{\alpha}  .$$
This shows that the sequence $\beta_i$ if unbounded.

thanks, I can stop looking for a proof now
